# Preprocess custom CCK fields and print image URL in TPL file

Tags: 6, theming

I want to preprocess a image field and later print it in my rss.tpl file and I'm currently using drupal 6.

This are the following codes I've tried in the template.php file but no luck :(

```
$vars['image'] = $field_uppdrag_logo;
```

&

```
/*$vars['image']=$node->field['field_uppdrag_logo'][0]['value'];
```

&

```
$vars['image'] = $node['field_uppdrag_logo'];*/
```

My tpl file:

```
<?php
// $Id: views-view-row-rss.tpl.php 3296 2009-05-27 23:08:21Z tim $
/**
* @file views-view-row-rss.tpl.php
* Default view template to display a item in an RSS feed.
*
* @ingroup views_templates
*/

?>
<item>
<title><?php print $title; ?></title>
<link><?php print $link; ?></link>

<description><?php
$description = html_entity_decode($description, ENT_QUOTES, "ISO-8859-1");
print strip_tags($description);
?>
</description>
<image>
<?php print $field_uppdrag_logo[0]['view']; print $image; print $field_uppdrag_logo;
?> 
</image>
<?php print $item_elements; ?>
</item>
```

How exactly do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Try the below:

```
$vars['image'] = $node->field_uppdrag_logo[0]['value'];
```

Comment: I'm using drupal 6

Comment: Thank you for your answer but does this work for drupal 6?

Comment: try to print the node and you can get the currect way of using it. I dont know how you have used the cck. if requre more help, try to pirnt the node using print_r and update it, so that i can have a look and tell u the exact way of using it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found some useful codes but none seems to work for me... it only prints the directory but not the filename...

```
<img src="<?php print $node->field_image[0]['filepath'] ?>" 
alt="<?php print $node->field_image[0]['filename'] ?>" />
```

.

```
print theme_imagefield_image($node->field_image[0]);
```

Cant understand why this would work for everyone else but not me...

Comment: Just prints "Array" ....

Comment: `$node->field_image[0]` will be an array... You need to print out the view/value/safe version in the level below... E.g. `$node->field_image[0]['value']`... But if you do a `print_r($node->field_image[0])` you'll see what it contains and be able to pass the 'file' variable [theme_imagefield_image()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--imagefield--imagefield.module/function/theme_imagefield_image/6) is expecting.

Comment: When try this "print theme_imagefield_image($image);" it just prints the <img  alt="" src="http://127.0.0.1/sites/default/files/" />

Comment: Have you set `$image`? You need to do what I said above to find the right value and pass that  (only when you know it's correct) to `theme_imagefield_image()`.